# Kerberos Error APP_MODIFIED when using a CNAME DNS record

Tags: active-directory, sql-server, iis, kerberos, spn

I have a production server, which I'll call `CONTOSO\MachineA`, running SQL Server. I have a development server, which I'll call `CONTOSO\MachineB`, running IIS. Both servers are running Windows Server 2008. I have a domain user, which I'll call `CONTOSO\MyAppSvc`. I have two CNAME records, `myapp => MachineA` and `myappdev => MachineB`.

My goal is to have (intranet) clients connect to IIS on `MachineB` and authentication via windows authentication, and then for the app to impersonate them and connect to SQL on `MachineA` as themselves.

MachineB is running another instance of SQL Server, for testing, and I have verified that SQL is set up right for double hop auth by running `SELECT * FROM [MachineA].[My App DB].App.SomeTable` via `SSMS (on MyWorkstation) => SQL Server (on MachineB) => SQL Server (on Machine A)`.

`MyApp` on IIS on `MachineB` is set up with Impersonation and Windows Authentication (Negotiate only) and running in `MyAppPool` which is running as `MyAppSvc`. `system.webServer/ security/ authentication/ windowsAuthentication @useAppPoolCredentials` is true and `@useKernelMode` is false. `MachineB` and `MyAppSvc` are both trusted for unconstrainted delegation. There are two SPNs on `MyAppSvc`: `HTTP/myapp` and `HTTP/myapp.contoso.local`.

Using wireshark, I see the following when I try to browse `http://myapp/aPage`:

- MyWorkstation => MachineB

  - **GET /aPage**
  - Host: myapp
- MachineB => MyWorkstation

  - **401 Unauthorized**
  - WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
- MyWorkstation => MachineB

  - **GET /aPage**
  - Host: myapp
  - Authorization: ticket:

    - realm: CONTOSO.LOCAL
    - sname: HTTP/MachineB.Contoso.local
- MachineB => MyWorkstation

  - **401 Unauthorized**
  - WWW-Authenticate:

    - error-code: ERR-MODIFIED
    - realm: CONTOSO.LOCAL
    - sname: MyAppSvc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the fact that the DNS entry is a CNAME record not an A record combined with fact that the SPNs are set up for the host name `MyApp` and not the machine name `MachineB`. The solution is to either change the DNS entry for `MyApp` to an A record that points directly to the IP address of `MachineB` or to add the SPNs `HTTP/MachineB` and `HTTP/MachineB.Contoso.local` (the old ones likely could be removed).